# Last value of last hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to extract la values from the last recording of the previous hour.
The Table have: DateHour (TIMESTAMP) and Energy (FLOAT)

```
Id________DateHour_____________Energy
..........................................................................
18350____2019-10-05 18:57:44____231.38
18351____2019-10-05 18:59:45____231.33
..........................................................................
..........................................................................
18400____2019-10-05 19:51:00_____123.35
```

The time now is 19:51:15 let say.

I want to select the value with ID 18351 in the example above. I want to work even when the day changes.

Tied:

```
select * 
from table1 
where DateHour> (unix_timestamp()*1000 - 60*60*1000);
```

Not good.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And by *previous hour* do you mean 60 minutes of time or from 18:00-19:00?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL (which the code looks like):

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where datehour >= cast(date_format(now() - interval 1 hour, '%Y-%m-%d %h:00') as datetime) and
      datehour < cast(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') as datetime)
order by datehour desc
limit 1;
```

MySQL doesn't have a convenient function (like `date_trunc()` in Postgres) that rounds a date/time value down to a particular unit.  In this case, it uses string conversion for this purpose.

Note that the structure of the query makes it possible to use an index on `datehour`.  That is important if an index is available and your table is large.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Only one think ,it gets the hour from the morning: 2019-10-05 07:59:55 232.39

Comment: got it: %H not %h